# Does Laravel Eloquent 'where' guarantee order?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

For example, does this:

```
Model::where('role', 'all')->orWhere('role','user')->first();
```

Always get the model where role is 'all' first, because where() is declared earlier than the orWhere()?

Or should I not trust that and always check with if?

```
$foo = new Model;
$bar = $foo->where('role', 'all')->first();
if(empty($bar)){
    $bar = $foo->where('role','user')->first();
}
```

Or maybe a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it will not, and it has nothing to do with Laravel, this is just how SQL works.

The query builder will generate the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Model WHERE `role` = 'all' OR `role` = 'user' LIMIT 1;
```

The order you will get the rows in will be the order they are in the `Model` table. If you want to get the rows sorted you will have to apply an order to the query, for example:

```
Model::where('role', 'all')
    ->orWhere('role','user')
    ->orderByRaw('CASE role WHEN \'all\' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END DESC')
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Model::whereIn('role', ['all', 'user'])->get();
```

If you want to order results and get only first one you can specify order like this:

```
 Model::whereIn('role', ['all', 'user'])->orderBy('some_column', 'ASC')->first();
```

But of course you can do it your way like this:

```
Model::where('role', 'all')->orWhere('role','user')->orderBy('some_column', 'ASC')->first();
```